# Retrieving some particular tables from database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have many tables in database but I want to retrieve data from some particular tables

I am doing this as follows:

```
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

but from this I am getting all tables present in database. But I want to retrieve only some tables with particular pattern. The pattern is something like this

```
a_employee_raw
a_employee2_raw

b_employee_raw
b_employee2_raw
```

Also want to check if these tables contains data or not. Please suggest.

Comment: And doing the filtering in your application is not an option? Why not?

Comment: I want to retrieve particular tables as database contains 1000 tables..retrieving all and then filtering will take much time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [the documentation of `DatabaseMetaData.getTables`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-)? It says:

> `tableNamePattern` - a table name pattern; must match the table name
>   as it is stored in the database

And the introduction text of `DatabaseMetaData` it says:

> Some `DatabaseMetaData` methods take arguments that are String
>   patterns. These arguments all have names such as `fooPattern`. Within
>   a pattern String, "`%`" means match any substring of 0 or more
>   characters, and "`_`" means match any one character. Only metadata
>   entries matching the search pattern are returned. If a search pattern
>   argument is set to `null`, that argument's criterion will be dropped
>   from the search.

In other words it behaves as a `LIKE` search. Assuming your specific database stores table names in upper case (check `storesUpperCaseIdentifiers()` and friends in the metadata), you can use something like:

```
md.getTables(null, null, "__EMPLOYEE%_RAW", null);
```

This might match a little wider, as the second and third `_` will match any character and not just a literal underscore, and the `%` will match things other than numbers.

If your database stores tables by default in lowercase (or if these tables where created quoted and are actually stored lowercase), then you need to use:

```
md.getTables(null, null, "__employee%_raw", null);
```

Note that it might be better to use the following to address the problems with matches wider than the literal underscore (`_`)

```
md.getTables(null, null, "_\\_EMPLOYEE%\\_RAW", null);
```

but I'm not sure if all JDBC drivers actually support SQL `LIKE`-escapes in the pattern.